# Custom keys in json_encode array

Tags: php, mysql, json

I'm retriving data from mysql. in my php I've got 2 arrays set

```
 $main =array(); //tostore retrived data
 $list =array('instock' => 'output1', 'item' => 'output2'); //existing key values and new key value to be replaced
```

How do I replace the keys with custom keys for each output? exmpale: custom keys `output1`,`output2`

current output

```
[{"instock":"yes", "item":"ch00024"},{..}]
```

Expected output

```
[{"output1":"yes", "output2":"ch00024"},{..}]
```

This is what I have tried so far. But does not work.

```
     $main =array(); //tostore retrived data
     $list =array('instock' => 'output1', 'item' => 'output2'); //replace key values

     foreach ($result as $key => $value){ 
        $main[  $list[ $key ] ] = $value; 
     }
     echo json_encode( $main );
```

I get an error `Undefined offset: 0`. It points to this line `$main[  $list[ $key ] ] = $value;`

**EDIT**

This is a screen capture from my console

[image]

var_dump():

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["instock"]=>
    string(3) "yes"
    ["item"]=>
    string(6) "it0215"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["instock"]=>
    string(3) "yes"
    ["item"]=>
    string(6) "it0381"
  }
  so on...
```

Comment: What are you getting in $key.

Comment: @RavindraBhalothia Thank you. when I echo `$main[  $key ] = $value;` it outputs `4`. I have no idea where did 4 came from?

Comment: Ok you're getting 0 in key and you're checking that in associative array. You need to get column name in $key so that only you're code works. Means $key must be instock or item.

Comment: @RavindraBhalothia Thanks again. I didn't follow. What's wrong in my code? `$list` has the value and its relevant word I need to replace.

Comment: Could you please share var_dump of $result. It will help to understand where is the glitch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works! The issue is in `$list` array you need define all keys in `$result` otherwise you need to check if there is that key in `$list` array.

```
$result =array(
    'instock' => 'yes',
    'item'    => 'ch00024',
    'color'   => 'blue',
    'price'   => 100
);

$main = array();

$list = array('instock' => 'output1', 'item' => 'output2');

foreach ($result as $key => $value){ 
    if (!empty($list[$key])) {
        $main[$list[$key]] = $value; 
    }
}
echo json_encode($main);
```

**Edit**

Because you are access 2 dimensional array, so you need an extra loop to go through all items

```
$result = array(
     array (
        'instock' => 'yes',
        'item' => 'it0215'
     ),
     array(
        'instock' => 'yes',
        'item' => 'it0381'
     )
);

$main = array();

$list = array('instock' => 'output1', 'item' => 'output2');

foreach ($result as $item){ 
    foreach ($item as $key => $value) {
        $main[$list[$key]] = $value; 
    }
}

echo json_encode($main);
```

The output is

```
{"output1":"yes","output2":"it0381"}
```

But In case you want to get all items with key replacement in new array. You should do something like this:

```
foreach ($result as $index => $item){ 
    foreach ($item as $key => $value) {
        $main[$index][$list[$key]] = $value; 
    }
}

echo json_encode($main);
```

The output is:

```
[
  {"output1":"yes","output2":"it0215"},             
  {"output1":"yes","output2":"it0381"}
]
```

Comment: Thnks. Why do we have to use an if statement?

Comment: As you can see, the $result array have 4 key-value pairs, but in $list we only have 2 key-value pairs. For example $list['price'] will raise an undefined  index error.

Comment: btw, what is your `$result` looks like? @Becky

Comment: Thanks. Please see my edit. That might give you a better idea.

Comment: Your console ouput is from client side, but your `$result` is on server side. One is PHP and one is Javascript.

Comment: Ok. I've added `var_dump()` for better understanding

Comment: Now I see the issue, because you are accessing two dimensional array, I will update the answer.

Answer (score 1):

try to this code

$flippedList  = array_flip($list);